# Does G-d have a sense of humor?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, humor

Is there scriptural evidence, from the Tanakh (not Talmud) that humor is an attribute of G-d? If so, can a chapter or verse be cited?

Comment: Is this different from [jokes in Tanach](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21874/are-there-any-jokes-in-tanach)?

Comment: I'm closing this per the comment exchange on the answer. Ephraim, if you [edit] it to clarify exactly what you seek and how it's different from the preexisting question, it can certainly be reopened. I don't want lots of people posting lots of answers that are not actually what you're looking for and that go in all sorts of directions: that doesn't help you and it doesn't help future seekers for specific things.

Comment: @msh210 How is G-d having a sense of humor, as it were, in any way the same as there being jokes in Tanach?

Comment: @Loewian, the answer below gives examples of jokes, and the OP commented that he seeking stuff from _Tanach_. So he seems to be happy with jokes as an answer but wants them to be from _Tanach_. (And God's having a sense of humor would be evinced by the jokes in _Tanach_, I guess.) But I await his edit if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @msh210 Actually, it seems pretty clear he's looking for (explicit?) Scriptural references to divine humor, so still not a duplicate.

Comment: @Loewian, there's no need for the two of us to hash out what Ephraim's intent was: he can speak for himself by editing the question, or by commenting on the answer clarifying that an answer like that (but from _Tanach_ instead of _G'mara_) doesn't match his intent, or by some other means.

Answer (score 1):

Jewish action deals with the question [Does God Have a Sense of Humor?](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/05/2013/does-god-have-a-sense-of-humor/) and says that humor is an essential part of the Talmud. Rabbi Hershel Schachter (Nefesh HaRav, p. 69) cites Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik as suggesting that the statement is important for the mitzvah of *vihalachta biderachav* (following in God’s ways)

> we are told approvingly that Rabbah, prior to beginning his lecture,
>   would open with a milta dibidichuta, a humorous remark. As a result,
>   his students, notably described as “rabanan” (which would counter the
>   notion that such a method is only necessary or appropriate for
>   children) had their “hearts opened” to learning. The Talmud practices
>   as it preaches. It is related that Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan was once asked
>   if there are any jokes in the Talmud, and his response was, “yes, but
>   they’re all old.”
>
> A cursory reading of the Talmud’s text validates that assertion. An
>   informed reading may yield that jokes are not only present in the
>   Talmud, but abundant. The Talmud’s pun in reference to bedikat
>   chametz (Pesachim 9b) is well-known; finely-tuned eyes have uncovered many more, as
>   documented in an extensive article in the Bar-Ilan journal Badad.
>   (Binyamin Engleman, “Humor Mutzhar, Galuy vi-Samuy bi-Talmud Bavli,” Badad, vol. VIII (winter 5759)). As
>   the author of that article, Binyamin Engleman, notes, the message is
>   twofold: that the sages of the Talmud were capable of joking and, more
>   significantly, that these jokes were worthy of memorializing in the
>   Talmud itself (as he puts it, “jokes with a hechsher”).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question which asks specifically about G-d's humor directly being mentioned somewhere.

Comment: I was hoping for Tanakh examples. I wouldn't be surprised to find Talmudic humor.

Comment: @Ephraim If you were hoping for _Tanach_ examples, then the answer to Scimonster's question (in a comment on your question post), "Is this different from [jokes in Tanach](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21874/are-there-any-jokes-in-tanach)?", would seem to be "No" and this question is a duplicate of that question. Right?

Comment: No, I wouldn't consider this a duplicate. I'm not asking about jokes, I'm specifically asking if humor is an attribute of G-d and if there are Tanakh references to show this.

Comment: @Ephraim I think that you now have two separate quesions. The frirst "Does Hashem have a sense of humor?" I deal with here. The second "Are there explicit Tanach references to the sense of humor?" would be dealt with in the other question. Are you asking if Tanach says "Hashem has a sense of humor."

Comment: I'm not sure how the question can be worded with any more clarity. I'm simply asking if Hashem has a sense of humor, if so, are there Tanakh examples? If they are perceived as two different questions, then I'd be happy to post them separately.