# Can one have a favorite pasuk/parsha/masechta?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, talmud-gemara

This closed question asks for a '[favorite pasuk](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/what-is-your-favorite-passuk)', presupposing that such a thing is allowed.

When it comes to sugyos or sections/topics of Torah, Chazal say on the one hand, (Eiruvin 64a) that a person may not say that 'one section of the Torah is nice, and another is not nice', but on the other hand it seems permissible to *enjoy* one section more than the other, as we are advised that a person learns best from a topic that he enjoys the most (Avodah Zara 19a). Does this mean that a person can privately be drawn to a particular section, but not express it, or only express it in the form of a subjective opinion?

By saying, 'sugya X is great', one is implying that sugya Y is less great, and that would seem to be prohibited. However, Chazal appear to have done that themselves, as they would refer to certain topics as 'great sugyos' (ex: Bava Kama 20a). Is that allowed?

Furthermore, whatever the law is by sugyos, does it apply equally to pesukim? Perhaps one cannot say that he likes a particular pasuk more, as it implies that one pasuk is more important than another (against what the Rambam writes in Foundation 8 of his famous 13)?

I've seen this issue discussed, so I feel justified in asking for only sourced answers, please.

Comment: Unsourced: I heard that only the second part is the problem (I don't like this), not the first

Comment: @ShmuelBrin that does seem to be the case, but I don't see why - shouldn't one imply the other?

Comment: @Matt Because liking one does not mean the other is disliked. If i like chocolate ice cream more than vanilla ice cream, it does not mean that i dislike vanilla ice cream. I just happen to like chocolate ice cream even more. Call it a disposition if you will.

Comment: @BoruchTkatch but there's still a *relative* dislike. put in another way, the questions can be asked as thus: "is the problem with saying 'I like one sugya but not the other an issue because one is this saying that he dislikes a section of Torah, or is there inherently a problem with preferring one thing over another, i.e. Saying one is not likes as much? You read it the first way, but I'm inclined to read it the second way because then there's no need for the first half of the phrase לא יאמר אדם שמעתתא זו נאה

Comment: @Matt Good point on the first part. But the actual quote is: כל האומר שמועה זו נאה וזו אינה נאה מאבד הונה של תורה  a) It is a statement about the person. b) The person makes a statement about a שמועה (which is not a pasuk) c) He loses הונה של תורה not that it is assur. My reading is that by saying one is nice and one isn't nice (as opposed to one being comparatively nicer) he is "picking favorites" and from thence comes the problem.

Comment: @BoruchTkatch good point made by you as well; I probably should have looked up the phrase before asking my question. I still think that this question is discussed

Comment: @Matt "כל האומר שמועה זו נאה **וזו אינה נאה** מאבד הונה של תורה" implies that only if one says that one is good **and** one is bad. Just by saying that one is good does not fall into that category. Also, it doesn't mean that the others are bad. It means that the person has a greater liking for it, but not to, chalilah, be denigrating all others.

Answer (score 7):

The [Sde Tzofim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_4238_16.pdf) says

> ולכאורה יש להעיר מהך דעירובין(סד) א״ר אתא ב״ר
>    מאי דכתיב ורועה זונות יאבד הון, כל האומר
>    שמועה זו נאה ושמועה זו אינה נאה מאבד הונה של
>    תורה. ופרש״י, רועה זונות, נוטריקון זו נאה וארענה
>    ואעסוק בה כדי שתתקיים בידי. עכ״ל. ועיין ברש״ש שם.
>
> אמנם יש לומר כי הקפידה מצאה לנוח דוקא במקום
>    שאומר ג״כ זו אינה נאה. אבל זו נאה בלבד שפיר
>    דמי.
>
> וכן משמעות דברי המאירי בעירובין (שם) שכ׳, אסור
>    לאדם שיעשה עצמו מכריע בדברי תורה לומר זו
>    הגונה וזו אינה הגונה, שמתוך כך ישפיל בהכרעתו את
>    שאינן הגונות בעיניו. ושמא טעה בעיונו וגרם לשכח
>    הלכות גדולות. דרך צחות אמרו, רועה זונות יאבד הון
>    וכו׳. וענין המשל הוא שהנשים חינן חלוק לבני אדם, זו
>    נאה לזה וזו נאה לזה, וכן השמועות אין ראוי לדחותן אלא
>    להתיישב בטעמן, וכשיעיין בדבר ימצא הכל נאה ומתוקן.
>    עכ״ל.
>
> אולם המהרש״א בח״א שם כ׳, דמשמע דזו נאה נמי לא
>    יאמר, דבהכי איירי קרא דאייתי רועה זונות
>    אחרות שאינם נאות. ע״כ
>    וכן משמע מדברי הט״ז בדברי דוד (ר״פ קרח), שהקשה
>    עמ״ש בפרש״י שם פרשה זו יפה נדרשת במדרש
>    תנחומא. שהרי האומר שמועה זו נאה מאבד הונה של
>    תורה. וזו נאה לבד ג״כ אסור. וע״ש מ״ש ליישב בדרך
>    דרש. עיי״ש.
>
> ועיין בס׳ קיצור של״ה (דף נ״ג ע״ד), שכ׳ להזהיר את
>    המוכרים עליות ס״ת בבהכ״נ, שנוהגים לומר בפר׳
>    עשרת הדברות וכיו״ב, שפרשה זו נאה. וכתב, שציוה
>    הגאון מהר״ר שמואל אב״ד דפירדא שלא יכריזו כן,
>    דמשמע שפרשה אחרת ח״ו אינה נאה. עיי״ש. ולכאו׳ נר׳
>    דס״ל כד׳ מהרש״א הנ״ל. ועיין בס׳ שלחן הקריאה
>    (ילקוט דוד, די״א ע״א) מ״ש בזה.
>
> וע״ע בס׳ בן יהוידע (עירובין סד) שהקשה דהא אם
>    אומר שמועה זו נאה אדרבה הוא משבח השמועה
>    וכו׳. ותי׳, כי זה האומר זו נאה ודאי שלא על כל הלכה
>    ששומע אומר כן, אלא יזדמן שלא יאמר כן על כמה
>    הלכות. וכיון שיודעים שדרכו לומר שמועה זו נאה, ועל
>    שאר ההלכות אינו אומר כלום, נמצא שהוא מבזה לשאר
>    ההלכות. עיי״ש. ומבואר מזה דס״ל שאף שמועה זו נאה
>    בלבד אין לומר

He said that it's an argument. The Meiri says that it's forbidden only to say "I *don't*  like this teaching", while the Maharsha, Taz, Kitzur Shela and the Ben Yehoyada say that it's also forbidden to say "I like this teaching", as it implies that if one *doesn't* say anything, he *doesn't* like the teaching.

Ahh, but what about places where it says "This was explained nicely in the Medrash"?

The Taz writes:

> לכאורה קשה שיש איסור בלשון זה שהרי ארז"ל
>     שאסור לומר הלכה זו נאה הלכה
>    זו אינה נאה׳ דא״ל דדוקא תרווייהו
>    יש איסור לומר ז״א דהא הלכה זו
>    אינה נאה לחוד יש איסור אלא ע״כ
>    דה״ק כשם שאסור לומר הלכה זו אינה
>    נאה כך אסור לומר הלכה זו נאה״
>    דמתוך זה משמע שהלכות אחרות אינם
>    נאים ח״ו וא״כ למה אמר רש״י פרשה
>    זו כו'. וי״ל דגם כאן יש מיעוט דבשאר
>   מקומות יש ב׳ דרכים האחד לפי פשוטו
>    והשני לפי המדרש אבל כאן אין כאן
>    אלא דרך אחד דהמדרש הוא פשוטו
>    שאין כאן פשוטו רק המדרש הוא יפה
>    נדרש אפי׳ לפי פשוטו דאין שום פירוש
>    על ויקח מה לקח לפי פשוטו

He said that "It's explained nicely" doesn't mean that "In *other* places the Medrash doesn't explain nicely" but that "this is the *only* (or one of the only places) where the Medrash is Peshat). Perhaps this idea can be extended to other places where the Gemara says "Teach us a nice teaching".

Comment: +1. Even the strict opinions would not seem to have any problem if someone was careful to use phrasing that could not be taken to imply that other parts of Torah are not nice. E.g. "I particularly enjoyed learning this *sugya*," or, "This *pasuk* resonates with me especially much."

Comment: All the sources of Sdeh Tzofim were previously cited by R. Ovadiah Yosef in Yabia Omer vol. 2 (YD §16), in a question about saying "this *sefer* is very good". He concludes that when one does not add "...and this one is not good", in essence (intentionally) disparaging the other, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Midrash Tanchuma:

מעשה בחסיד אחד שהיה מתייחד במקום אחד והיה למד בו במסכת חגיגה, והיה מהפך בה ומהדרה כמה פעמים עד שלימד אות ההיטב שגורה בפיו. ולא היה יודע מסכת אחרת מן התלמוד. והיה שוגה בה כל ימיו. כיון שנפטר מן העולם היה בביתו לבדו ולא היה שום אדם יודע פטירתו. באתה דמות אשה אחת ועמדה עליו והרימה קולה בבכי ומספד. נתרבה אנחתה וצעקתה עד שנתקבצו ההמון ותאמר להם ספדו להחסיד הזה וקברוהו וכבדו את ארונו ותזכו לחיי העולם הבא שזה כבדני כל ימיו ולא הייתי עזובה ולא שכוחה. מיד נתקבצו כל הנשים וישבו עמה ועשו עליו מספד גדול ועצום. והאנשים נתעסקו בתכריכו וכל צרכי קבורתו וקברו אותו בכבוד גדול. ואותה אשה בוכה וצועקת אמרו לה מה שמך, אמרה להם חגיגה שמי. כיון שנקבר אותו חסיד נעלמה אותה אשה מן העין. מיד ידעוש מסכת חגיגה הייתה שנראית בצורת אשה ובאתה בשעת פטירתו לספוד לו ולבכותו ולקוברו בכבוד על שהיה שונה אותה תמיד ושיקד לילמד בה. עד כאן לשונו. ומזה יבין האיש הנלבב כמה גדול יהיה כוח מליצתה לעד על האיש הזה למעלה לצרור בצרור החיים את נשמתו ולהצילו מיום הדין הגדול והנורא שעתיד להיות לעתיד לבוא.

(I will be happy to translate if needed)

From this midrash you see that it is looked in a positive way to love a certain Sugiya or Masechet.

Comment: This is a quote from the Chafetz Chayim's *Toras HaBayis* ([fn. to 6:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15141&st=&pgnum=321)), quoting the *M'noras HaMa'or* who relates this story in the name of the *Tanchuma*. (Our editions of the *Tanchuma* do not have this story, however). The concluding sentence of this story (missing from the Chafetz Chayim's excerpt) indicates that it is preferable to study and focus on more than one *masechta*: "והלא דברים קל וחומר ומה חסיד זה שלא למד אלא מסכתא אחת בלבד כך הלמד תורה הרבה ותלמוד הרבה ומעמיד תלמידים הרבה על אחת כמה וכמה".

Answer (score -1):

Rabbeinu Yonah says on Avos that in order to be mekayem the mitzva of ve'ahavta le'reachah ke'mochah you should make one especially good friend and then extrapolate from your experiences with that person how you should behave towards other people.

Similarly the baalei mussar explain that a person should make 'friends' with one mesechta and then extrapolate out from that mesechta to develop an understanding of the other parts of the Torah.

I.e. it is fine to have a favourite mesechta which is your 'best friend' because this forms a gateway into the entirety of the Torah.

Comment: `in order to be mekayem the mitzva of ve'ahavta le'reachah ke'mochah` I read R' Yona on *Avos* 1:6 as simply saying one must treat his friend with *ahava* for the sake of maintaining the friendship. Does he say more elsewhere? | `a person should make 'friends' with one mesechta` This appears to be based on Rashi on *Avos* 1:6, who mentions that some say that "acquire a friend for yourself" refers to *s'farim* ("וקנה לך חבר אמרי לה ספרים"). Do you have a precise source who interprets this as befriending a single tractate to help understand and appreciate other tractates?

Answer (score -2):

There is a difference between saying : "I don't like this seyouga" and "this seyouga isn't nice".
If you say "I don't like this seyouga", you're speaking about you, and it's very normal to have preference.
But, if you say "This seyouga isn't nice", you're speaking about the seyouga and denigrating it and that is forbidden.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the insights. The only thing is, the question is asking if it is permitted to say "i *like* a sugya", not "i *don't* like a sugya". If you're able to answer that, please [edit] that in.